# F1 2011 Ego Database Editor

Tags: pc, mods, f1-2011

I've completed my fifth season now and want to start again. I was told if I want to start again with my last team (Mclaren) I should change the team ID to 4. I changed all teams to tier 4 and saved but I still get the same start teams.

I'm new to this so if I'm doing something stupid I apologize, but could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question. What do you mean by `Rider Database Editor`? And which platform?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do that with the editor, but here is the link to a mod that already does that for you.

Top 3 Teams Mod (F1 2011/database folder):
http://www.mediafire.com/?q9ie5af1i1aw43l

File to allow you to save the game with mods installed (it goes in you F1 2011/system folder):
http://www.mediafire.com/?m2468a8q5b87ono

Of course you can't play online with these files so make sure to back them up first.